# Probability of randomly selecting box B given that two red balls were sequentially drawn without replacement?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Box A has 3 red and 7 white, and Box B has 8 red and 2 white.

What is the probability that Box B is selected given 2 red balls are drawn? i.e. $$\Pr(\text{ Box B}\mid\text{2 red balls }). $$

I understand selecting Box B randomly = 50% chance (1/2), selecting 1st red ball = 80% chance(8/10), 2nd red ball = 77% chance(7/9), but I don't know how to put it all together and I feel like I'm missing something.

appreciate the help.

Comment: Pr(Box B|2 red balls) means "the probability that Box B is selected **given** that 2 red balls are drawn" not "the probability that Box B is selected and 2 red balls are drawn", Which one do you mean?

Comment: excuse me, I meant to say the 1st phrase "The probability that Box B is selected given that 2 red balls are drawn" computing Pr(Box B| 2 red balls). Can someone show me the product rule for this? When I try it I seem to be off. I've been told it's meant to equal 28/31

Comment: Firstly correct your question in the body to show what exactly you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your probability is

$$\mathbb{P}(B|RR)=\frac{\frac{8}{10}\cdot\frac{7}{9}}{\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{2}{9}+\frac{8}{10}\cdot\frac{7}{9}}=\frac{56}{62}=\frac{28}{31}$$

as you expected to find

the chance of 50% selecting A or B is irrelevant being the same for the two boxes

Comment: Thank you!! I swear I tried this, but I must have miscalculated something I was only getting .83 I was loosing my mind